# Error: Type 'XX' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why `handle3` is getting this error.

All the three methods is the same with different notation, isn't it?
Is this a bug of ts?

```
type UseCaseResponse = Promise<any>


class Foo {
    async handle(): Promise<any> {
        return await Promise.resolve('x')
    }

    handle2(): UseCaseResponse {
        return Promise.resolve('x')
    }

    async handle3(): UseCaseResponse {
        return await Promise.resolve('x')
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json (typescript : 4.1.3)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ES5",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./resources/js",
        "types" : [
            "jquery"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        { "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Also this works for me in typescript playground.

Comment: Did you tried this in vscode with my tsconfig.json ?